# Format of values for GstBaseTextOverlay's color property

Tags: text, colors, overlay, gstreamer, pango

[The `GstBaseTextOverlay` object](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pango/GstBaseTextOverlay.html?gi-language=c) used for GStreamer's Pango-based plugins (`textoverlay`, `clockoverlay`, etc.) has a `color` property. [Its documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pango/GstBaseTextOverlay.html?gi-language=c#GstBaseTextOverlay:color) describes it as follows:

> `“color” guint`
>
> Color of the rendered text.
>
> Flags : Read / Write
>
> Default value : -1

A `guint` is an unsigned 32-bit integer, but the default value specified here (-1) is signed. The color component order is also unspecified (presumably red, green, blue, and alpha are each allocated eight bits).

Although these plugins use Pango, in Pango colors are represented using [the `PangoColor` struct](https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/struct.Color.html) (it contains three `guint16` values, one for each of red, green, and blue), which doesn't appear to be used in the context of GStreamer.

What is the format of values for `GstBaseTextOverlay`'s `color` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color component order is ARGB, or, in hex notation, `0xAARRGGBB`. For example:

- `0xFF000000` is opaque black
- `0xFF00FFFF` is opaque cyan (green and blue)
- `0x80FF0000` is translucent red (~50% opacity since `0x80` = 128, roughly half of 255)
- `0x00000000` is transparent

This is mentioned in [the description of the `outline-color` property](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/pango/GstBaseTextOverlay.html?gi-language=c#GstBaseTextOverlay:outline-color):

> `“outline-color” guint`
>
> Color to use for outline the text (big-endian ARGB).
>
> Flags : Read / Write
>
> Default value : -16777216

It's odd that the default values are presented as signed integers given that both properties use the `guint` type, but in big-endian form the default values correspond to the following:

- Default for `color`: -1 = `0xFFFFFFFF` (white)
- Default for `outline-color`: -16777216 = `0xFF000000` (black)